# How does a node gets deleted in linked list?

Tags: sorting, data-structures, linked-list, structure

While performing deleting a node operation in linked list, I have often come across with the code:

```
**head=head->next**
```

Where 'head' is the linked list and 'next' is the component of the linked list which links all node together .

How does this code actually change the members (delete the member) of the linked list.

Comment: I'm not sure which language would have you use the two asterisks. Do you mean *head = *head->next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Remy Cilia is correct, but something about your asterisks suggests that you're referring to something like this in C:

```
int remove_first(node_t** head)
{
    if (head == NULL || *head == NULL) return -1;

    node_t* save = *head;
    *head = save->next;
    free(save);

    return 0;
}
```

We are passing a double pointer to the function for a reason. If we passed a single pointer, we'd be doing this:

```
int remove_first(node_t* head)
{
    if (head == NULL) return -1;

    node_t* save = head;
    head = save->next;
    free(save); // bad idea

    return 0;
}

// before function call:
head->node->next->NULL
// during function call
head->node->next->NULL
head---^
// before return:
    head->NULL next->NULL // (anyone can correct this line, but we can still free that node I believe)
head-------------^
// after return:
 head->NULL next->NULL
```

The single pointer just creates a copy 
of the head pointer rather than 
modifying the original, which has never moved.

With a double pointer:

```
    // before function call:
    head->node->next
    // during function call
    head->node->next
head--^
    // before return:
    head->next
head--^
    // after return:
     head->next
```

Since the double pointer head is an address to the original head, we de-reference the double pointer to access the original head ponter rather than a copy of it. That way we are able to repoint the original pointer.

Comment: The delete function could return the updated (if needed) head pointer. The call would be head = delete(head, value), which would delete the first node with that value, or as another example it could be head = deletefirst(head).  Using a double pointer internally would still simplify the code, but a single pointer could be passed as a parameter.

Comment: @ rcgldr Thanks for the alternative answer.

Answer (score 1):

This code will delete the first element of the linked list.

If 'head' is the first element of the list, 'head->next' is the second element. Doing 'head = head->next' moves the second element to the first position. This way, next time you access your linked list with 'head', you will retrieve the second element, and the old first element is not in the list anymore.